# C# Events in C++

Tags: c#, c++, events, c++11, event-handling

I've been trying to get my own C# API (DLL) working in C++11. My API fires certain events when needed. These events are the key to the entire API.

Now I was asked to try and make it work in combination with C++, so I followed this tutorial: http://support.microsoft.com/kb/828736 and everything went well. Until I got stuck.

(Please note that this is test code to simplify my problem, I know it's an infinite while-loop, I fixed that in my own version using signals)

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include "tchar.h"
#include <signal.h>
#import "C:\Users\Enzo\Documents\visual studio 2012\Projects\MyDLL\MyDLL\bin\Debug\MyDLL.tlb" raw_interfaces_only
using namespace MyDLL;

bool run = true;

int _tmain(int argc, _TCHAR* argv[])
{
    // Initialize COM.
    HRESULT hr = CoInitialize(NULL);
    IFooPtr foo(__uuidof(Foo));

    // hook the handler to the event
    foo->add_Bar(/*No idea what goes here, in my opinion it should be the function to call when the event is triggered.*/);

    while(run);

    // Uninitialize COM.
    CoUninitialize();

    return 0;
}
```

The `foo->add_Bar(MyDLL::_MyDelegate* value)` comes from my C# DLL (I think):

```
namespace MyDLL
{
    public delegate void MyDelegate();

    public interface IFoo
    {
        event MyDelegate Bar;
    }
}
```

But I have no idea what to do with it. It wants a `MyDLL::_MyDelegate*` parameter, but I have no idea how to attach a `MyDLL::_MyDelegate*` to a function. Or if that is even necessary?

If further information is needed, please tell me.

Comment: Google "COM connection points", first hit looks decent.

Comment: Isn't that a bit of overkill for what I want to achieve?

Comment: That's the typical response when a programmer finds out how events are handled in COM.  The under-kill in C# or the automatic mapping of an event to a function in a scripting language is indeed very convenient.  No such convenience in C++, you are programming the bare metal.